# How to export PDF from back-end list using DynamicPDF plugin in OctoberCMS

Tags: export, octobercms

I am going to use DynamicPDF plugin to export pdf from backend list in OctoberCMS.
But I don't know how to use this plugin with export button in backend list.
So I hope your kind assistance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, Just follow this steps.

> **1.  Add link for export**

add this code to your `_list_toolbar.htm` **[** you can find this file inside your plugin and controller's view files **]**

```
<div data-control="toolbar">
    <!-- ..some default code... -->

    <a href="<?= Backend::url('hardiksatasiya/timetracker/timelog/export') ?>" 
        class="btn btn-primary oc-icon-sign-out">export</a>

</div>
```

> **note:** replace `link Url` with your **author/plugin/controller** then leave **export** action name as it is

> **2. Creating template for our PDF file in `DynamicPDF Plugin`**

Create New template

Set It's code : `export-data-pdf` **[I am using this but you can use your own]**

**(make sure this code we will use later to generate PDF)**

Set It's HTML

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">        
    <tr>
    {% for header in headers %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>        
    {% for record in records %}
    <tr>
        {% for data in record %}
            <td>{{ data }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}        
</table>
```

Save it.

> **3. Add `export` named action inside your controller** `[As you said DynamicPDF is installed so we can use \Renatio\DynamicPDF\Classes\PDF in it]` . This action will generate your PDF file, and we call this action from **STEP-1 link**.

```
public function export()
{
    $lists = $this->makeLists();
    $widget = reset($lists);

    /* Add headers */
    $headers = [];
    $columns = $widget->getVisibleColumns();
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $headers[] = \Lang::get($column->label);
    }

    /* Add records */
    $getter = $this->getConfig('export[useList][raw]', false)
        ? 'getColumnValueRaw'
        : 'getColumnValue';

    $model = $widget->prepareModel();
    $results = $model->get();
    $records = [];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $record = [];
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $value = $widget->$getter($result, $column);
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = implode('|', $value);
            }
            $record[] = $value;
        }
        $records[] = $record;
    }
    return \Renatio\DynamicPDF\Classes\PDF::loadTemplate('export-data-pdf',
        ['headers' => $headers, 'records' => $records])->stream('export.pdf');
}
```

> **4. Customization**

As this code will read your `list-config` and generate PDF according to it but if you want to `customize` it you can edit given `export` action and generate your data set according to that. And `PDF template changes` you can do from `DynamicPDF` plugin.

If any doubts please comment.